# What would cause a connection refused (wireshark: [RST,ACK]) error?

Tags: rhel, socket

I have a service running on my RHEL 8 server VM on port 9092. When I send messages to this port from a client, the connection times out. WireShark shows that the server responded with a [RST,ACK], as shown below (RHEL VM's IP is ...121.30):

[image]

Even though I can see the port is open using netstat.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9092            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I've also tried clearing firewall rules.

What else could I try?

Comment: Check the log of your service? Do you have selinux enabled?

Comment: *"WireShark shows ..."* - where is the packet capture done? On the client side or on the server side or somewhere in between (like VM host)? Could you do packet captures on each side to see what the client and server systems actually get?

Comment: @nobody selinux is disabled on the server. My service produced no log because the message never reached it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich wireshark trace was captured on the client side, and there's no host inbetween. I'll work on capturing wireshark on the server side.